# Issue with fieldset format in multiselect cheboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have the below code in my html page, the issue is with the multiselect checkbox of the div element of id 'alot'

```
<div id="pagePreferences" class="pageDefault pageAlertsPreferences" data-role="page" data-class="com/xyz/abc/Controller">

  <div id="header" data-role="header">
    <!-- Loads header here -->
  </div>

  <div class="contentRegular" data-role="content">

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="c">

      <label class="inline">Yes or NO</label>
      <select id="togButton" class="slider" name="flip-1" data-role="slider">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on">On</option>
      </select>


      <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="alot">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

          <div style="font-weight: bold" id="checkBoxes">Business Category:</div>

          <input type="checkbox" value="All" class="checkBoxClass" id="ckbCheckAll" />
          <label for="ckbCheckAll">All</label>

          <input type="checkbox" value="29" class="checkBoxClass" id="29" />
          <label for="29">ABC</label>

          <input type="checkbox" value="30" class="checkBoxClass" id="30" />
          <label for="30">BCD</label>

          <input type="checkbox" value="31" class="checkBoxClass" id="31" />
          <label for="31">CDE</label>


        </fieldset>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="navMenu" data-role="panel" data-animate="false">
    <!-- Navigation Menu is loaded here -->
  </div>

</div>
```

First i have hardcoded the values like the lables ( ABC,BCD,CDE). This works fine and i get the output like below.

[image]

But when i want to generate the muliselect cheboxes content from the javascript file(com/xyz/abc/Controller), 
i am not getting the multiselect checkbox in a proper format

Here is the screen shot

[image]

Here is the html :

```
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="alot">

        </div> -->
```

Javascript file :

```
var prefix = '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">' +
  '<div style="font-weight: bold" id="checkBoxes">Business Units:</div>' +
  '<input type="checkbox" value="All" class="checkBoxClass" id="ckbCheckAll" />' +
  '<label for="ckbCheckAll">All</label>';

var subfix = '</fieldset>';

var html = "";


$('#alot').append(prefix);

for (generate the data from db) {

  html = '<input type="checkbox" value="' + unitID + '" class="checkBoxClass" id="' + unitID + '"' + '/>';
  html = html + '<label for="' + unitID + '"' + '>' + unitName + '</label>';

  $('#alot').append(html);

}


$('#alot').append(subfix);
```

What might be missing here ? Why the look & feel of the multi select checkboxes is not same when I generate the content dynamically ?

Comment: "*...the issue is with the multiselect checkbox of the div element of id 'alot'*" - so, why are we looking at (apparently) *all* of your HTML, and not just *that specific `<div>`?

Comment: David - I also put the code thinking it may impact the multi checkbox group!! Sorry for that.

Comment: check dynamically generated content with inspect Element and see if there is any missing code or improper class definitions, it may be styling issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically added elements, you should *enhance* them manually using jQM's methods. The simplest way is using `.enhanceWithin()` called on parent div. This method will create any widget within that div in spite of its' type.

```
/* create controlgroup and append "All" checkbox to it */
var ctrlgrp = $("<div/>", {
    "data-role": "controlgroup",
    id: "checkBoxes"
}).append('<input type="checkbox" value="All" class="checkBoxClass" id="ckbCheckAll" /><label for="ckbCheckAll">All</label>');

/* loop through your data array and append checkboxes to ctrlgrp */
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    ctrlgrp.append('<input type="checkbox" value="value' + i + '" class="checkBoxClass" id="cb' + i + '"' + '/><label for="cb' + i + '"' + '>Checkbox ' + i + '</label>');
}

/* append all elements to "alot" div and then enhance the elements */
$("#alot")
    .append(ctrlgrp)
    .enhanceWithin();

/* check/uncheck checkboxes
   with change event delegated to it
   since it's dynamically added */
$("#alot").on("change", "#ckbCheckAll", function () {
    $(this)
        .closest(".ui-controlgroup")
        .find("[type=checkbox]")
        .prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"))
        .checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/qobubo/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: Thanks again!!. Its working now. I have another problem, if I can't solve it, I will post it as a separate question.